# ios show video/Audio like live streaming

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, live-streaming

i have videos/Audios on the Server, i want to show to user like Its Live Streaming.Like if the video time is 5pm to 7pm and if the user opens at 6pm then it should show video from the 6pm and it should not show user control for reverse and forward video/audio

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your video's with the appropriate metadata (store the air-times somewhere). 
Let's call that air-time [`Ta`]. Once a user opens a video, check the local device time [`Td`].

Now seek the video towards `Td - Ta` as that is the offset of the pseudo realtime within that video.

You will certainly have to do some extra check on videos that have expired etc.

For your second question; removing parts of the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s controls isn't allowed. So you could implement your own UI and deactivate the default one or you could go ahead and use `AVPlayer` right away as you will have to implement your UI anyways. I'ld recommend using `AVPlayer` in this case.

Comment: v good and Explained Answer.i have just one more question.how will i be able to cut the Video that is been Wasted.is it possible to remove that part like in my above question the video of 5pm to 6pm is wasted video

Comment: Why "cutting" it when you can simply seek to 6pm using your code. The user will not be able to seek anyways, hence 5pm-5:59pm will not be reachable for him.

Answer (score 0):

We have to encode our live streaming into HLS formate such as .m3u8,mp4 and any other HLS support formate in iOS.Apple did't approve live streaming without HLS formate.you can use wowza media server to encode your server url to HLS formate for support in iOS and then you can play it through MPMoviePlayerController in iOS.